# Batch video presenting (playing, pausing, going to specific time, ...) in Linux

Tags: linux, video, script, batch, video-playback

Is it possible to write an action file (e.g. a script) that plays some video files?
I need it to be programmable to automatically perform these actions:

- start from a specific time
- **play up to a specific time**
- going to a specific time
- changing playing speed
- pausing
- going to next video file

Can VLC or Mplayer do this? what's the easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use a playlist in VLC. It supports some special commands like start, stop and pause.
 Like this example:

> #EXTM3U
>   #EXTINF:,Video title 1
>   #EXTVLCOPT:start-time=0
>   #EXTVLCOPT:stop-time=25 
>   Video_filename1.wmv
>   vlc://pause:10
>   #EXTINF:,Video title 1
>   #EXTVLCOPT:start-time=25
>   #EXTVLCOPT:stop-time=35 
>   Video_filename1.mp3
>   #EXTINF:,Another movie
>   #EXTVLCOPT:start-time=35
>   #EXTVLCOPT:stop-time=120
>   Anothermovie.avi

Paste into a m3u-file and play with VLC.
This would play the first 25 secs of Video_filename1.wmv, pause for 10 secs, play 10 secs more and then jump to Anothermovie.avi at 35 secs into the move and the play 2 minutes.

Comment: Thanks,is it possible to pause until i resume by myself?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't think so. You can still use the manual controls in VLC or start it with `--play-and-stop` to make VLC pause after each playlist item.